# Prove: if a set A ⊆ ℝ² is not bounded according to the metric d₂, it is also not bounded according to the metric d∞

Tags: real-analysis

This is a question from a past exam we had on an Analysis course.

If a set $A ⊆ ℝ^2$ is not bounded according to the metric $d_2$, it is also not bounded according to the metric $d_\infty$.

Term is not over, so its possible I am missing some material, but really we didn't cover much.

I thought that it might be possible to use this theorem I do know:

$d_\infty(P,Q) \leq d_2(P,Q) \leq \sqrt k \cdot d_\infty(P,Q)$

But really, I'm not that sure what to do here. Any ideas?

Comment: May be useful to know that the metrics $d_2$ and $d_\infty$ are.

Comment: You can do by contradiction by knowing the defnition.

Comment: If it were bounded, then you could cover it with a $d_\infty$ ball of radius $R$. But then this is covered by a $d_2$ ball of radius $\sqrt 2 R$.

Comment: If you can put the right value in for $k$ in the theorem that you know, you should be able to get there,.